# Esse meu algortimo não está lendo o meu arquivo por completo, está lendo só apartir da 435º linha até a linha 990º

Tags: c++

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
 
typedef int TipoChave;
typedef int TipoDado;
typedef string TipoNome;
    struct TipoRegistro {
    TipoChave chave;
    TipoDado dado;
    TipoNome nome;
        
    }TipoRegistro[1000];

void Imprimir(){
     for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
        cout << TipoRegistro[i].chave << " / ";
        cout << TipoRegistro[i].dado << endl;
        cout << TipoRegistro[i].nome << endl;
        
    }
    
}
   

void Preencher_Estrutura(string nomedoarq){
    int chave,dado,i=0;
    string nome;
    ifstream arquivo;
    arquivo.open(nomedoarq);
   while(!arquivo.eof())
   {
       arquivo >> chave;
       arquivo >> dado;
       arquivo >> nome;
        TipoRegistro[i].chave = chave;
        TipoRegistro[i].dado = dado;
        TipoRegistro[i].nome = nome;
        i++;
   }
    arquivo.close();    
} 

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
     string conteudo;
    ifstream arquivo;
    Preencher_Estrutura("GeraSeq1000.txt");
    Imprimir();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: não seria porque não está vendo as linhas anteriores sendo exibidas? tenta mudar o `for` na function `Imprimir` para contar de 0 a 50 por exemplo e valdar

Comment: Não sei se entendo seu programa. Se quer ler os registros do arquivo porque manter os 1'000 registros na memória? Se `Imprimir()` mostra os registros a partir do que está no vetor na memória para que o arquivo? E como vai saber o que gravou se não leu do arquivo e sim do vetor?